# how to use exponential learning rate in tensorflow object detection?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

Can anyone tell how to set **exponential learning_rate** instead of constant learning rate in the config file?

Constant learning rate in config file:

```
learning_rate: {
            manual_step_learning_rate {
              initial_learning_rate: 0.003
              schedule {
                step: 6000
                learning_rate: .0003
              }
              schedule {
                step: 12000
                learning_rate: .00003
              }
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly how the config file should be used. Other than that, `tf.train.exponential_decay` provides exactly what you need.

Comment: this site is confuse me. i cant find a direct example.

Answer (score 6):

Refer 
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/optimizer.proto

Example:

```
learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.004
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
```